# How are you supposed to NAT with Snow Leopard Server mini with only 1 ethernet port?

Tags: macos, networking, osx-snow-leopard, ethernet, nat

How are you supposed to NAT with Snow Leopard Server mini with only 1 ethernet port?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do virtual interfaces on the mini and trunk them at the switch, though a home user wouldn't have a switch that supports 802.1q.

The solution that most home users would probably use is buying Apple's USB to Ethernet adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLANs or add a second network adapter, but you don't have to. NAT works perfectly fine even if the two IP networks share a physical Ethernet segment.